# Some character are missing when getting properties with : java.lang.System.getProperty();

Tags: java

I'm trying to get value from properties but some of them contains `>` which seems to cause an issue...

for exemple :

I have 3 tomcat properties

`-DTEST_USERNAME=admin`

`-DTEST_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd>`

`-DTEST_HOST=google.com`

the following line :

```
console.log(java.lang.System.getProperty('TEST_PASSWORD'));
```

should return : `Pa$$w0rd>`
but insteed return : `[console.log]<no source name> - Pa$$w0rd=google.com`

is this how it's supposed to work or some kind of issue ?
should I change the password to remove the `>` ?

Additional information : java 8

Link to javadoc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-

Comment: `console.log`? That is Javascript, not Java

Comment: since I'm using a java method I think that the java tag is still accurate ( I might be wrong )

Comment: Yes, but where is `console.log` actually running? In Java, you would use `System.out.print`

Comment: it's running in a Javascript file but since the issue is on java method I don't know which tag is accurate

Comment: @Ashuni It would help if your question included more details on how Tomcat is launched. My answer won't help you unless you run Tomcat from a launch script (eg cmd / bash), I'm unsure about how Javascript would be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The greater than ">" is a file redirection in some terminals / shells. On Windows use double quotes around the definition:

```
java "-DTEST_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd>" ...
```

On Unix/Gnu/Linux/Bash use single quote or double quote with escaped `\$` which avoids having `$$` replaced by process id:

```
java '-DTEST_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd>' ...
java -DTEST_PASSWORD='Pa$$w0rd>' ...
java "-DTEST_PASSWORD=Pa\$\$w0rd>" ...
```

On later JDK versions you can validate that your settings would be passed in correctly by using `-XshowSettings:properties` parameter. For example, try:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties "-Dsomeproperty=val>ue" 2>&1 | more
```

Which should print:

```
Property settings:
    ...
    someproperty= val>ue
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but I think more correct format would be `-Dproperty='value'`.

Comment: @OneCricketeer You are right for bash though WIndows CMD does not like single quote so I've amended my answer with both styles.

Comment: I agree with OneCricketeer: `-DTEST_PASSWORD='Pa$$w0rd>'` is the more *nix idiomatic

Comment: for : "-DTEST_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd>" I have this result : `Pa$$w0rd=google.com`


for : -DTEST_PASSWORD="Pa$$w0rd>" I have this result : `Pa$$w0rd=google.com`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by putting the Pa$$w0rd> in Base64

```
-DTEST_PASSWORD=UGEkJHcwcmQ+
```

and then decoding the value in javascript with return : `Pa$$w0rd>`